# Why can't I use the logging module on Python 3.10?

Tags: python, logging

A simple code I want to run to discover what "logging" module is:

```
import logging

logging.debug('This is a debug message')
```

This code is not working for me. I'm on SublimeText 3, my Python version is 3.10

I've got pip version 22.0.4, ez_setup version 0.9 and setuptools version 61

The logging module is in my lib:(picture)
I don't understand...
Can you help me please?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? It raises an exception? What's the traceback? Is the actual behavior not what you expected?

Comment: I'll take a wild guess that you have your own module named `logging.py`.  Don't do that.  Name your module something else that does not conflict with a standard module name.

Comment: It works fine; you just didn't configure the root logger to display debug messages. (The default level is `WARNING`).

Comment: traceback: is [finished ] so nothing was printed my module name is different then logging.py and i've configured the root logger with level WARNING NB:what is the difference between logging and logger?

Comment: OK it works with level DEBUG and NOTSET now .It works fine, I can see the debug !!! ...and i know the difference between logging and logger(silly question).

Answer (score 0):

The default output for Python logging is stdout, so if it is working it must print to the console. Why is not it working? Because first of all you must get a logger

```
logger = logging.getLogger('__main__')
```

Then you must set the level. By default DEBUG is not logging.

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Now it must work

```
logger.debug('your message')
```

Comment: Thanks, now that i've got a logger and that i've setted the level it works , but it doesn't print anything .

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel), the root logger is created with level `WARNING`, hence the `debug` call is ignored. You can change the level with [`setLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel):

```py
>>> import logging
>>> logging.debug('test')
>>> logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.debug('test')
DEBUG:root:test
```

Comment: Thank you , that helped me understand how the module must be set to work.